# Проблемы с программой для сортировки чисел

Tags: c++, сортировка, консоль, переменные

Появилась проблема. Мне нужно написать программу, в которой пользователь задает 4 числа, после чего эти 4 числа сортируются. Первыми должны быть написаны не четные по возростанию, а потом четные по уменьшению.
**Вот так пытался сделать это я**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int func(int x,int y,int z,int k);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    int key = 1;
    while (key == 1){
        int a1, b, c, d;
        cout << "\n Developer: 123456\n";
        cout << "\n Enter a, b, c, d number: \n";
        cin >> a1 >> b >> c >> d;
        int x,y,z,k;
        func(x,y,z,k);
        cout << "\nEnter 1 for repeat, else 0";
        cin >> key;
    }

    return a.exec();
}

int func(int x,int y,int z,int k){
    int a1,b,c,d;
    x=a1%2;
    y=b%2;
    z=c%2;
    k=d%2;
    if (x==0){
        if (y==0){
            if (z==0){
                if (k==0){
                    if (b<c) swap (b,c);
                    if (a1<b) swap (a1,b);
                    if (c<d) swap (c,d);
                    cout << "\n" << a1 << b << c << d;
                }
                else {
                    if (b<c) swap (b,c);
                    if (a1<b) swap (a1,b);
                    cout << "\n" << d << a1 << b << c;
                }
            }
            else if (k==0){
                if (a1<b) swap (a1,b);
                if (b<d) swap (b,d);
                cout << "\n" << c << a1 << b << d;
            }
            else {
                if (a1<b) swap (a1,b);
                if (c>d) swap (c,d);
                cout << "\n" << c << d << a1 << b;
            }
        }
        else if (z==0){
            if (k==0){
                if (a1<c) swap (a1,c);
                if (c<d) swap (c,d);
                cout << "\n" << b << a1 << c << d;
            }
            else {
                if (a1<c) swap (a1,c);
                if (b>d) swap (b,d);
                cout << "\n" << b << d << a1 << c;
            }
        }
        else if (k==0){
            if (a1<d) swap (a1,d);
            if (b>c) swap (b,c);
            cout << "\n" << b << c << a1 << d;
        }
        else {
            if (b>c) swap (b,c);
            if (c>d) swap (c,d);
            cout << "\n" << b << c << d << a1;
        }
    }
    else if (y==0){
        if (z==0){
            if (k==0){
                if (b<c) swap (b,c);
                if (c<d) swap (c,d);
                cout << "\n" << a1 << b << c << d;
            }
            else {
                if (a1>d) swap (a1,d);
                if (b<c) swap (b,c);
                cout << "\n" << a1 << d << b << c;
            }
        }
        else if (k==0){
            if (a1>c) swap (a1,c);
            if (b>d) swap (b,d);
            cout << "\n" << a1 << c << b << d;
        }
        else {
            if (a1>c) swap (a1,c);
            if (c>d) swap (c,d);
            cout << "\n" << a1 << c << d << b;
        }
    }
    else if (z==0){
        if (k==0){
            if(c<d) swap (c,d);
            if (a1>b) swap (a1,b);
            cout << "\n" << a1 << b << c << d;
        }
        else {
            if (a1>b) swap (a1,b);
            if (b>d) swap (b,d);
            cout << "\n" << a1 << b << d << c;
        }
    }
    else if (k==0){
        if (a1>b) swap (a1,b);
        if (b>c) swap (b,c);
        cout << "\n" << a1 << b << c << d;
    }
    else {
        if (a1>b) swap (a1,b);
        if (b>c) swap (b,c);
        if (c>d) swap (c,d);
        cout << "\n" << a1 << b << c << d;
    }
}
```

По итогу в консоли выводится какой-то набор цифр, которые я не задавал переменным.

---

Спасибо за помощь. Нашел ошибки

Comment: **так же еще думал сделать массивом, но я не знаю как присвоить элементу массива значение переменной**

Comment: Ну правильно. Вводите числа a1, b, c ... А потом заводите неинициализированные переменные x,y,z ... и с ними запускаете вашу функцию. Получится ерунда

Comment: а вопрос то зачем удалили?

Answer (score 2):

кажется этот вопрос вы уже задавали или не вы :)

если используется c++, то почему бы не воспользоваться функцией сортировки `std::sort`?

а в качестве алгоритма сортировки `(a, b)` выбрать следующий:

1. если `a` чётное, а `b` нечётное - то `false`
2. если `a` нечётное, а `b` чётное - то `true`
3. если `a` и `b` имеют одинаковую чётность, то сравнить `a < b`

алгоритм задать в функции `std::sort` через лямбда-функцию

```
[](const int a, const int b) {
    // алгоритм
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115709/discussion-on-answer-by-zhihar------).

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы работает нормально, кому нужно, то пользуйтесь

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int func(int x,int y,int z,int k);
int coef(int &a1,int &b,int &c, int &d);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    int key = 1;
    while (key == 1){
        cout << "\n Developer: shisui\n";
        int x,y,z,k;
        func(x,y,z,k);
        cout << "\nEnter 1 for repeat, else 0";
        cin >> key;
    }

    return a.exec();
}

int func(int x,int y,int z,int k){
    int a1,b,c,d;
    coef(a1,b,c,d);
    x=a1%2;
    y=b%2;
    z=c%2;
    k=d%2;
    if (x==0){
        if (y==0){
            if (z==0){
                if (k==0){
                    if (a1<b) swap (a1,b);
                    if (b<c) swap (b,c);
                    if (c<d) swap (c,d);
                    cout << a1 << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << ' ' << d << endl;
                }
                else {
                    if (a1<b) swap (a1,b);
                    if (b<c) swap (b,c);
                    cout << d << ' ' << a1 << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << endl;
                }
            }
            else if (k==0){
                if (a1<b) swap (a1,b);
                if (b<d) swap (b,d);
                cout << c << ' ' << a1 << ' ' << b << ' ' << d << endl;
            }
            else {
                if (a1<b) swap (a1,b);
                if (c>d) swap (c,d);
                cout << c << ' ' << d << ' ' << a1 << ' ' << b << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (z==0){
            if (k==0){
                if (a1<c) swap (a1,c);
                if (c<d) swap (c,d);
                cout << b << ' ' << a1 << ' ' << c << ' ' << d << endl;
            }
            else {
                if (a1<c) swap (a1,c);
                if (b>d) swap (b,d);
                cout << b << ' ' << d << ' ' << a1 << ' ' << c << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (k==0){
            if (a1<d) swap (a1,d);
            if (b>c) swap (b,c);
            cout << b << ' ' << c << ' ' << a1 << ' ' << d << endl;
        }
        else {
            if (b>c) swap (b,c);
            if (c>d) swap (c,d);
            cout << b << ' ' << c << ' ' << d << ' ' << a1 << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (y==0){
        if (z==0){
            if (k==0){
                if (b<c) swap (b,c);
                if (c<d) swap (c,d);
                cout << a1 << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << ' ' << d << endl;
            }
            else {
                if (a1>d) swap (a1,d);
                if (b<c) swap (b,c);
                cout << a1 << ' ' << d << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (k==0){
            if (a1>c) swap (a1,c);
            if (b>d) swap (b,d);
            cout << a1 << ' ' << c << ' ' << b << ' ' << d << endl;
        }
        else {
            if (a1>c) swap (a1,c);
            if (c>d) swap (c,d);
            cout << a1 << ' ' << c << ' ' << d << ' ' << b << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (z==0){
        if (k==0){
            if(c<d) swap (c,d);
            if (a1>b) swap (a1,b);
            cout << a1 << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << ' ' << d << endl;
        }
        else {
            if (a1>b) swap (a1,b);
            if (b>d) swap (b,d);
            cout << a1 << ' ' << b << ' ' << d << ' ' << c << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (k==0){
        if (a1>b) swap (a1,b);
        if (b>c) swap (b,c);
        cout << a1 << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << ' ' << d << endl;
    }
    else {
        if (a1>b) swap (a1,b);
        if (b>c) swap (b,c);
        if (c>d) swap (c,d);
        cout << a1 << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << ' ' << d << endl;
    }
}
int coef(int &a1,int &b,int &c, int &d){
    cout << "\n Enter a, b, c, d number: \n";
    cin >> a1 >> b >> c >> d;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте реализовать алгоритм, предложенный @Zhihar в его ответе, ибо он в разы проще, чем ваш) И его можно использовать с произвольным количеством чисел.

Comment: Я понимаю, но попробую это сделать, когда получу необходимые знания, поскольку сейчас я не знаю как его реализовать